# How stop ffmpeg write to log command line strings

Tags: php, ffmpeg, php-7

I save mp3 to mp3 via `shell_exec();`and use logs for error control

```
FFREPORT=file=ffreport%p%t.log:level=16
```

But if I change `level=16` to `level=0`

every convertion I still get ffreport%p%t.log files with text:

```
Command line:
ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/php2hmlyt  -acodec copy /home/uploads/5607.mp3
```

How stop write to logs useless Command line data?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-redirect-output-and-errors-to-devnull/), you may want to log to /dev/null, which is very similar to [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/555289/is-there-a-way-to-disable-or-hide-output-thrown-by-ffmpeg)

Hope will help!

Comment: sorry, this is not work. i think problem not in stdout params

Answer (score 0):

From `man ffmpeg` I have:

> quiet, -8       Show nothing at all; be silent.
>
> panic, 0 Only show fatal errors which could lead the process to crash, such as and assert failure. This is not currently used for anything.
>
> error, 16 Show all errors, including ones which can be recovered from.

Try the **-8** value. It should help.

Comment: I create a ticket https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5242 They says this is not a bug get command line string in file if i select "-8" value :-(